# Good tutorials on how to add form fields with jquery

Tags: jquery

What are some good tutorials on how to add form fields with jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Charlie Griefer probably has the best documented tutorial on this I've come across](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/9/17/jQuery--Dynamically-Adding-Form-Elements)

Adding a form element can be as simple as:

```
$("form").append("<input type='text' id='bob' />");
```

It all depends how complex your forms are and what you're ultimately after, but Charlie's tutorial is a good place to start.